# integrated windows authentication equivalent for java and linux

Tags: java, linux, authentication

For windows there is integrated windows authentication.
We can configure active directory and join the cleint to the domain.
Then all the services on the client that communicates with the iis on the server can use the integrated authentication transparently.

Is there something similar for java, linux and some application server ?

Regards

Comment: Are you looking for something as complete as NTLM for Ldap running on Linux? Do you want to have the authentication credentials automatically passed in from the browser to your application?

Comment: Yes I like the credentials to be automatically passed to the app server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [LDAP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/) and PAM.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410507/linux-server-account-management), where you can find info.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the steps for Moodle, to get NTLM working in Apache, on Linux, as that may be what you are looking for, since you already have active directory.

http://docs.moodle.org/en/NTLM_authentication#APACHE_Configuration

This will be between apache and the browser, so, if you want it to work with Tomcat, then you may need to have to use JK (http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) to have connections come in to apache then be forwarded to tomcat, after authentication takes place.